# Does css/main.css serve some other purpose?

Tags: css

I am having the strangest issue...

At its most bare form, I have an `index.html` file with the following content:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

(I have stripped it down considerably in the process of trying to determine the root cause)

When I view the source of the page, I get the following:

```
<style>html,button,input,select,textarea{color:#222}body{font-size:1em;line-height:1.4}::-moz-selection{background:#b3d4fc;text-shadow:none}::selection{background:#b3d4fc;text-shadow:none}hr{display:block;height:1px;border:0;border-top:1px solid #ccc;margin:1em 0;padding:0}img{vertical-align:middle}fieldset{border:0;margin:0;padding:0}textarea{resize:vertical}.chromeframe{margin:0.2em 0;background:#ccc;color:#000;padding:0.2em 0}.ir{background-color:transparent;border:0;overflow:hidden;*text-indent:-9999px}.ir:before{content:"";display:block;width:0;height:150%}.hidden{display:none!important;visibility:hidden}.visuallyhidden{border:0;clip:rect(0 0 0 0);height:1px;margin:-1px;overflow:hidden;padding:0;position:absolute;width:1px}.visuallyhidden.focusable:active,.visuallyhidden.focusable:focus{clip:auto;height:auto;margin:0;overflow:visible;position:static;width:auto}.invisible{visibility:hidden}.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after{content:" ";display:table}.clearfix:after{clear:both}.clearfix{*zoom:1}@media print{*{background:transparent!important;color:#000!important;box-shadow:none!important;text-shadow:none!important}a,a:visited{text-decoration:underline}a[href]:after{content:" \(" attr(href) "\)"}abbr[title]:after{content:" \(" attr(title) "\)"}.ir a:after,a[href^=javascript:]:after,a[href^=#]:after{content:""}pre,blockquote{border:1px solid #999;page-break-inside:avoid}thead{display:table-header-group}tr,img{page-break-inside:avoid}img{max-width:100%!important}@page {margin:0.5cm}p,h2,h3{orphans:3;widows:3}h2,h3{page-break-after:avoid}}</style>
```

Weirdly enough, my `css/main.css` file has **nothing** in it.

I have confirmed these CSS rules appear across all browsers I've tested.

Where are these rules coming from? And how come if I rename the file `css/test.css`and reference it appropriately, this behavior disappears?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a cache issue?

Comment: That is an inline stylesheet. It does not appear to be related to the stylesheet you are linking to.

Comment: `.chromeframe` - That look [familiar](https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/)?

Comment: @JoelMurphy: Yeah, I've cleared my cache numerous types, went in incognito mode for Chrome, and switched to browsers that had never opened the page before. Same issue every time.

Comment: @Asad: Interesting. I noticed it has to be css/main.css and not just main.css . Any reason for that? Also, is this standard across all browsers? Can you point me in the direction of some info so I can read up on this? Thx

Comment: @JaredFarrish: It might be related to what Asad was saying.

Comment: I just looked at the *inline `<style>` tag content and picked out the `.chromeframe`*, which may be a clue as to where the CSS comes from? Do you *have* Chrome Frame installed? If you don't, it's awfully odd to show up. These browser tools (like Firebug, for instance) use browser-related scripts oftentimes to *inject* scripts and markup to achieve their work, and Chrome also provides Content Scripts access. Why it's in your "source" may depend on how you define "source".

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">` doesn't "inject" the inline style that you see in your HTML file. The `<style>...</style>` part that you see in your page source is not coming from `main.css`

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Good idea, but I don't. I'm on a Mac and Chrome Frame doesn't support OS X. If you visit http://pauli.ec, you'll see what gets generated. And that all happens with a simple: <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

Comment: @Arbel: How come when I remove the reference to css/main.css the style tags return to normal then? (e.g. <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.css">) instead of the rules above.

Comment: Now that I think about it, my link tag is actually being replaced by a style tag..

Comment: Well, you really haven't given enough details to understand the even the situation, "except it happens in all browsers". Investigate where the css comes from and you might find out what might be doing it. *Reading* it, it has the makings of a print stylesheet. If there's a scripting language involved, Varnish, or whatever else might be tampering or manipulating the output from the server (is there a Javascript maybe with a `document.write` somewhere?), I don't know.

Comment: Thanks @JaredFarrish. Sorry about the lack of info. I'm still trying to wrap my head around it. I think I isolated the behavior to only existing on the server. When I copy the code locally, the issue doesn't apear. I wonder if Dreamhost is doing something fancy on their side...

Comment: Wireshark (on Win7) says the packet from you server returns with that `<style>` markup in the response body, so whatever is doing it appears to be happening on your server.

Comment: Thanks Jared! Yeah, I just tested this with Telnet to take the browser out of the equation. Same result. I'm searching around right now to see if my host (Dreamhost) does anything on their side that could be causing this behavior....

Comment: I have Dreamhost on a site and that's never happened with the basic setup. So some reverse proxy or cache control (if they offer that) or something related may be interfering, or the file you *think* is responding isn't (you're not actually getting the file you're editing on the server). You could do a file search on your server to find that string; 20 characters or so would probably be enough to only get a few responses, if you avoid line-breaking syntax blocks (it looks minified).

Comment: @PaulCalabro Do you still need the answer to your question? I just checked back here.

Comment: Yeah, if possible. I'm looking in my host's admin panel to see if anything is configured that would explain this behavior

Comment: Your host could be injecting a reset CSS. It could be due to an application (e.g a CMS like WordPress) you have installed on your account **through** your control panel. If you can test it with other accounts on the same host you can find out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. I backed up my data, destroyed everything related to my domain on the host, and restored my files. This has resolved the issue. The only thing I can think of that I did a ways back was install some Ruby gems (in an attempt to learn RoR). I'm not sure if that played any part. Either way, it's solved. Thanks again! You guys rock!